# Java : Certificate self signing a jar

Tags: java, security, certificate

I've not done certificate stuff in a while, and I'm looking for a little bit of help.

Ideally I'd like to achieve this.

- Create jar.
- Sign with certificate.
- Have code inside that jar validate that it is signed with that certificate.

I've created a selfsigned certificate.

```
keytool -genkey -keyalg RSA -alias selfsigned -keystore keystore.jks -storepass password -validity 360 -keysize 2048
```

exported its public certificate

```
keytool -storepass password -alias selfsigned -export -rfc -file outfile.txt.cer -keystore keystore.jks
```

signed the jar

```
jarsigner -keystore keystore.jks -signedjar signedX.jar x.jar selfsigned
Enter Passphrase for keystore: password
```

I then have a class in the Jar that loads the outfile.cer and validates that this jar is signed against that.

Does this sound reasonable to you?

I'm signing the jar with my Private Certificate, then including the Public certificate in the jar and making sure its signed with the same certificate.

To me the big hole seems to be that I can un-jar the jar, change the code, sign with a NEW-Private-Cert, include the NEW-Public-Cert in the jar, and it will be valid.

I presume the solution to this problem is to have some external key store to validate against, not the certificate in my jar. Does this sound reasonable?

I appreciate this is a bit of an open question, and more of a design question than a single-correct- answer-question.

Any advice would be great.

---

EDIT...

Thinking about this overnight, I've realised the mistake in my process.

I need to import the PUBLIC certificate into the the Keystore on the client.
Then when I sign my jar with the private key, the client jvm will validate it.
I don't need to do any checking internally.

I'll test this out and then write up my findings.

Comment: The is no such think like a "NEW-Private-Cert", only a private key exists. And you don't have to include your (public) certificate into the JAR, it is added automatically included in the signature.

Comment: The solution is not to use a self-signed certificate, but instead use a certificate with a chain of trust back to a trusted root authority, of which, the public certs are installed in Java.